# How to select users in message table in MySQL and order them by date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a messaging module in MySQL and PHP. I have a table in which I am saving the messages.

The table for messages has the following columns:

```
Index | from | to | date | body
```

Now I want to select the users who sent or received text from a specific user and order that by date.

If I am user 2, table:

```
Id | from | to | date                | body
 1 | user1 | user2 | 2018-06-18 12:51:19 | Hi
 2 | user2 | user1 | 2018-06-18 12:55:19 | Hello

 4 | user3 | user2 | 2018-06-18 12:55:19 | Hi
 5 | user2 | user3 | 2018-06-18 12:56:19 | Hello
 6 | user3 | user2 | 2018-06-19 01:55:19 | bolo
 7 | user2 | user3 | 2018-06-19 02:56:19 | Kya
```

If I am user 2, desired data:

```
  user3 | 2018-06-19 02:56:19
  user1 | 2018-06-18 12:55:19
```

Comment: Side note: You should try and stay away from using [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), they require special handling.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this yourself?

Comment: Show us your attempt

Comment: You problem statement does not correlate with your expected output. Do you mean to fetch latest row per user ?

Comment: yes I want to select last messages to or by user2 and order them by date.

Comment: Please help me with this.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @ChAMp Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
select friend, max(last_date)  msg_date
from (
    select 'to' AS friend, max(date) last_date
    from 'yourTable'
    where 'from' = 'user2'
    group by 'to'
    union all
    select 'from' AS friend, max(date) last_date
    from 'yourTable'
    where 'to' = 'user2'
    group by 'from'
)
group by friend;
```